# XAML typeahead disappear when adding my user control

Tags: wpf, visual-studio, user-controls, visual-studio-2012, winrt-xaml

When I add my user control to the code in a XAML page the typeahead which prompt for elements and attributes stops working in that page. Everything works fine in runtime and I can display and use the user control as I want to, but in design time something gets corrupted.

If I comment out the user control using `<!-- -->` type-ahead starts working again. So while editing the XML I keep it commented, but it is a bit inconvenient to comment/uncomment every time I want to edit and then build & run.

The `local` namespace defined is shared among all classes in the project.

```
<local:MySettings Visibility="Collapsed" x:Name="MySettings" />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All of a sudden I notice that typeahead is working again...

As far as I know I did two things:

1. I did a Rebuild (instead of Build) in order to see if there were any warning messages
2. I closed VS to work on other things, and reopened just now.

Don't know which one of these was the cure for the problem, but at least it disappeared!

Answer (score 0):

This often means your control is doing something that upsets the designer.  Check the output tab/window to see if there is any output?